# Substituting the arrays to the function in python

Tags: python, list, iteration, equation, substitution

I want to substitute number (from first column of my long data file) to an equation with iteration and make the all calculated result in list.
Let's say I want to use `y=2*x+1` as an equation and `x` is one of the numbers in the first column of my data file. My main problem is `x` is not same as the row number. Since I have separate data files, each row of first column of my data has a different unrelated number.

My attempt so far:

```
for n in data[n,0]:
    result = []
    if n<100:
        y = 2*x + 1
        result.append(y)
        print result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had the following data file:

```
1 abc
2 abc
3 abc
4 abc
15 abc
```

The below script would parse the file for the number in the first column, apply your function, then append the number to a list (named results).  The code will need to be adapted depending on the format of your data file.

```
results = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        results.append(2*float(line.split(' ')[0]) + 1)

print results
[3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 31.0]
```